# How to get email and send Email To Multiple Values In People Picker Field In SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, person-or-group

Any ideas how I can easily send email from multiple values in person and group field using power automate?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Figured it out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apply to each action to loop over multiple selection person or group column and collect all email addresses in single string variable (separated by semicolon).

[image]

Check below threads for more information:

1. [Send one e-mail to multiple selection person or group column](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Send-one-e-mail-to-multiple-selection-person-or-group-column/td-p/841370)
2. [Sending email to multiple people from people picker in SharePoint list](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sending-email-to-multiple-people-from-people-picker-in/td-p/133001)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the links.

The first is incomplete but the second is nearly correct. I added a correction based on the need for a second compose statement to concatenate the variable holding the string of email addresses to the next email address in the Apply_to_Each loop. It works for me now!