# Get the email addresses of a People/Group field which allow multiple selection inside my Select

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a People/Group SharePoint field named "Person" which allow multiple selection >> and I am getting the related list items (which contain the "Person" field) using Get Items as follow:

[image]

Then inside the Select I want to select the Person email addresses to build a comma separated string for all the Person emails  >> but I only get the Person property, as follow and did not get a property for the Person email:

[image]

So can anyone advice?

Comment: Try turning OFF experimental features and see if it is showing Person Email property in Select action: https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/how-to-turn-on-experimental-features-in-power-automate/

Comment: @GaneshSanap what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: With experimental features turned ON, you have different user experience. For example in your images, "Filter query" is easy to add by selecting options from drop down but you don't see Person Email field in Select. In case you turn OFF the feature, you have to write your own filter query without drop down options and you will get Person Email field to use in Select action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Select **Person** in **From** property of Select action
2. Use expression like below in **Map** property of Select action

```
item()['Email']
```

**Action**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

You can also check my answer on this thread for different approach to achieve the same requirements to collect email addresses: [How to get email and send Email To Multiple Values In People Picker Field In SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305078/how-to-get-email-and-send-email-to-multiple-values-in-people-picker-field-in-sha/305109#305109)