# "Selected User" inside workflow designer 2013, how it works

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, designer-workflow, power-automate, flow

I have a workflow designer 2013 which I want to redesign using Microsoft Flow. The workflow designer 2013 has this "selected User" action:

[image]

Where Capital Request Settings is a SharePoint list which have a field named Person (of type People/Group which allow multiple selections and allow users & groups), as follow:

[image]

[image]

So will this action simply build a list of all the Person users from the list? and how I can map this action inside Power automate flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Capital Request Settings:Person` in context of current item in designer workflow, it returns the value of Person column for that respective list item for which workflow ran.

In Power automate flow, when you use trigger based on SharePoint list or use "Get Item (s)" action using SharePoint connector, you can get Person column values from **Dynamic content** section.

**Example**:

[image]

**OR**

[image]

Check my answers on below threads to collect email addresses from multiple selection person or group column in Power automate flow:

1. [Get the email addresses of a People/Group field which allow multiple selection inside my Select](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306950/get-the-email-addresses-of-a-people-group-field-which-allow-multiple-selection-i/306960#306960)
2. [How to get email and send Email To Multiple Values In People Picker Field In SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305078/how-to-get-email-and-send-email-to-multiple-values-in-people-picker-field-in-sha/305109#305109)