# Join multiple mails from output to send for approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, power-automate, flow

I have multiple person in approve list. My output result is:

```
[
  {
    "": "mail1@mail.com"
  },
  {
    "": "mail2@mail.com"
  }
]
```

I need to format it as:
`mail1@mail.com;mail2@mail.com` to send it for approval.

Expression `join(body('Pokupimailove'),';')` also doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: From where you get the output you mentioned in your question (at the top)? Why key is blank (`""`)?

Comment: Check my answer given below. Let me know if it works or if you face any issues while using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **Select** and **Compose** actions like this:

**Select** action:

Use "Switch to text mode" option as highlighted in below image and then use below expression in "Map" section (copy-paste as given):

[image]

**Expression used**:

```
@{item()?['Email']}
```

**Compose** action:

Use expression like below in compose action:

```
@{join(body('Select'),';')}
```

---

You can also use "Apply to each" action and collect all the emails in one string variable, check: [How to get email and send Email To Multiple Values In People Picker Field In SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305078/how-to-get-email-and-send-email-to-multiple-values-in-people-picker-field-in-sha/305109#305109)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now.